# How do you know if stock warrants are american or european style?

Tags: stock-exchanges, brokerage, warrants

On interactive brokers i was looking at some put warrants for GE which are being traded on the frankfurt exchange but  i don't know if  i can exercise them when i want, since I don't know if the exercise style is American or European.

Comment: Why would you want to exercise early? Can you not sell them for more than the gain of exercising?

Comment: I'm using a paper account not the live one, so it won't allow me to short warrants. Also even if I could sell them for more wouldn't the order take longer to fill rather than just exercising it?

Comment: Why would you want to exercise early?  That usually means more spread slippage and commissions.  See if you can find a prospectus for the warrant's details.  Why do you want to short the warrants rather than the options?

Comment: Because with exercising the put warrants i can choose the number of shares i wish the company to buy back but with shorting the options, if i short a call wouldn't i have to sell a 100 shares to the call buyer if they exercise. Also wouldn't i have to hope they choose to exercise so that I can gain the profit, since the call will be out the money in order to get a gain from selling it?